# Remove character range from NSTextStorage, but keep coloring the rest correct?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextstorage

I want to apply the same coloring of a NSTextView_A text to another NSTextView_B text, with just a fragment of the text of NSTextView_A.

I applied the NSTextView_A text coloring to NSTextView_B with NSLayoutManagerDelegate and

```
- (NSDictionary *)layoutManager:(NSLayoutManager *)layoutManager shouldUseTemporaryAttributes:    (NSDictionary *)attrs forDrawingToScreen:(BOOL)toScreen atCharacterIndex:(NSUInteger)charIndex effectiveRange:(NSRangePointer)effectiveCharRange
```

and then i deleted a character range in NSTextView_B text with:

```
[[_sourceCodeTextView textStorage]beginEditing];
[[_sourceCodeTextView textStorage]deleteCharactersInRange:    NSMakeRange(0, 253)];
[[_sourceCodeTextView textStorage]endEditing];
```

as described in [Changing Text Storage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TextStorageLayer/Tasks/ChangingTextStorage.html)

**The problem now is, that the characters get deleted correctly, but the coloring of the text before deletion is applied without respecting the new range.**

As an example: NSTextView_A text is blue in range 0-253 and e.g. everything behind green. After i delete the characters in NSTextView_B text (0-253), the resulting text is blue and afterwards green, but not just green.

**How can i make the coloring to respect the new text fragment?**

Comment: In that moment you post the content of the delegate method you will probably find your fault yourself. ;-)

Comment: @Amin:`return [(id<NSLayoutManagerDelegate>)self.editorTextView layoutManager:layoutManager shouldUseTemporaryAttributes:attrs forDrawingToScreen:toScreen atCharacterIndex:charIndex effectiveRange:effectiveCharRange];`Here i should probably edit the charIndex and effectiveCharRange.But my output stays all black, when i just change the effectiveCharRange.By setting the same (the whole text of TextView_A) text to TextView_B everything is colored correctly.I cannot find any further documenation on this delegate method and i am not able to restrict it to my fragment range.What do i get wrong?:-)

Comment: `self.editorTextView` is View_A?

Comment: yes and self.sourceCodeTextView View_B

Comment: So you take the range for the temporary attributes of the target text from another method, which returns a range that does not depend on the text of the target? What let you expect that this range will change, if the target text changed? It would be easier to use `NSAttributedString` and set the attributes in the target text. This lets the user edit the target text.

Comment: i tried that already by  `[_sourceCodeTextView.textStorage setAttributedString:[self.editorTextView.textStorage mutableCopy]];` but then the text is black. Removing all attributes before i apply the attributed string does not work either: `NSRange area = NSMakeRange(0, [_sourceCodeTextView.textStorage length]);
    [_sourceCodeTextView.textStorage removeAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName range:area];` and because of that also a NSAttributed-Substring of editorTextView applied to the target results in black text color.

Comment: source textview is the XCode source code editor textview and after enumerating the attributes i found out, that XCode's textstorage is missing the NSColor key. How can i access the colors of this textstorage?

Comment: Xcode uses clang for analyzing the source code. clang have options for analyzing sources in memory while editing. So maybe they do not store the information with usual keys for attributed string, maybe they do not store the information in the string as attributes at all. (I. e. Xcode needs that information for completion, too. So there might be a additional storage for that information somewhere else, likely a transformed AST. The AST delivers the information in the format: "Node with keyword X at position 165-179") Unfortunately I do not know an easy way to do, what you want to do. Sorry.